# jQuery navbar conflicts with lightbox++

Tags: jquery, lightbox

So I have a lightbox++ on my site, with a jquery I’m using on the navbar of the mobile query part of my site, and from what I’ve gathered, they’re conflicting with each other.

I attempted using the $.noConflict() placed above and under the jquery script tags, as well as basically all over the place, and nothing worked. But placing the noConflict line would reverse what worked in that moment. So if the navBar was working without the noConflict line, with the line added, it would then not work, but then lightbox would work, etc., and vice versa. So it’s affecting something in some way.

I’m just not a developer or steeped enough in this stuff to get the navbar and the lightbox to simply work together.

Some sites I see with the presumed solution, don’t take into account noobs like me that need to be deliberately walked through on where exactly to place the noConflict line and exactly how to modify it, given my exact lines of code on my site.

Really frustrating.

Here is the test page I’m working on: https://www.solarinkgraphics.com/index_TEST002.html

Here are the lightbox++ files linked in the body of my html, above the jquery:

```html
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox++.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function GroupDelegate(id) {
        var objLink = document.getElementById(id);
        Lightbox.prototype.start(objLink);
    }
    
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    lightbox.option({
      'fitImagesInViewport': true,
      'wrapAround': true
    })
    </script>
```

Here is the jquery, and javascript file, linked in the body of my HTML, under the lightbox files:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you talk about this "conflict", then it's ok, you must set which object should user light box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   lightbox.option({
     'fitImagesInViewport': true,
     'wrapAround': true
   })
</script>
```

Right now javascript looking for object lightbox for option method, but there is no lightbox object :)

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.my a tag with image).lightbox({  
     'fitImagesInViewport': true,
     'wrapAround': true
   })
</script>
```

// add a class='myclass_1" etc. for `<a class=''>` and then put them in ".my a tag with images like `$('.my_class_1).lightbox` ....

Overall, You have terrible mess in code :)